# python-how to properly select k best numerical features?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to apply `SelectKBest()` function over specific continuous numerical features from a pandas dataframe called `x_train`, meanwhile the label column is defined as a binary response variable (1,0) column called `y_train` :

```
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif


numerical_features=['col1', 'col2']

########################################################################

def get_numerical_features(features, class_label):
    
    class_label=pd.DataFrame(class_label)
    
    fs=SelectKBest(f_classif, k='all')
    
    for feature in features:
        fs.fit(class_label, feature)
        return(print('Feature %d: %f' % (feature, fs.scores_[feature])))
        
        
#######################################################################


# applying the function

get_numerical_features(features=x_train[numerical_features], class_label=y_train)
```

However when `get_numerical_features()` is applied, the output is the next one:

> TypeError: Singleton array array('col1', dtype='<U4') cannot be considered a valid collection.

What am I missing?

Is there any way to convert each column to a valid collection?

## data demo

```
x_train=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 7, 10, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 27, 3, 1]})

y_train=pd.DataFrame({'label': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

`fs.scores_` is actually an array of shape (2,) that you can't index with `feature`. Try:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif

numerical_features=['col1', 'col2']

def get_numerical_features(features, class_label):
    #class_label is already a Dataframe in your data demo
    fs=SelectKBest(f_classif, k='all')
    fs.fit(features, class_label) # this should be here 

    for i, feature in zip(range(len(features)), features): 
        print('Feature %s: %f' % (feature, fs.scores_[i]))
    
    
# applying the function
x_train = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 7, 10, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 27, 3, 1]})
y_train = pd.DataFrame({'label': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

get_numerical_features(features=x_train[numerical_features], class_label=y_train['label']) 

#output: 
#Feature col1: 0.486076
#Feature col2: 0.846043
```

> Is there any way to convert each column to a valid collection?

For this you can use `fit_transform` to automaticaly select your `k` features with highest score.

```
fs = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=1) # with `all` all features will be selected, default=10
x_train_new = fs.fit_transform(features, class_label)
print(x_train_new) # since k=1, this prints the values of col2 wich has high score
```